# Need to call a JSP object(jsonfile) inside my controller in angular 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a input file which i can see in my jsp file and it renders the json object.
I want to call this inside my JS file in the Angular controller.

The input file in JSP is.

```
 <input type="hidden" value=${getGlobalFeaturesList}
        ng-model="featureslistJson" id="getglobalfeaturelist">
```

In the controller i am calling

```
$scope.myData = ($scope.featureslistJson.ReadFeaturesResponse.feature);
```

Before this i was using external JSON FILE WHICH WORKS FINE

This call works fine

```
$http.get("script/data.json").success(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = (response.ReadFeaturesResponse.feature);
 });
```

How I do the same with the  featureslistJson

I get error cant read ReadFeaturesResponse.

Any help will be good.

Comment: What do you see when you do a `console.log` of the response?

Comment: The `.success` method has been [deprecated and removed from AngularJS v1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: @georgeawg

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReadFeaturesResponse' of undefined

Comment: @Insane Fragger getGlobalFeaturesList is null, try to print getGlobalFeaturesList in a div to discard

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive:

```
<div ng-init="myData = ${getGlobalFeaturesList}">
</div>
```

```
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch("myData", function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  })
})
```